# Not Able to Login to App When Running Local Instance of Node/Mongo API

Tags: node.js, angular

In my Angular front-end app, I pass values for `username` and `password` as well as an `API key` when logging in via a POST request. This has worked up until recently, both when I run a local instance of the API, and when I hit our secure, website URL-based API (ex: `https://securesite.com`). In both cases I am targeting the same database. However, over the last week or so I am not able to login when I run the local version of the API. I am still able to connect when hitting our secure website (with the exact same credentials).

I am running the local API at `http://localhost:3000`. When I `console.log`out the response the API returns in VSC, I can see that the correct info is being returned. However, when I hit this endpoint either through Postman, or through the Angular app running at `localhost:4200`, while pointing the API config to `http://localhost:3000`, the response just appears to hang - and eventually times out (again, even though I can see the correct response being logged out in my IDE).

In my Postman settings I also have "SSL certificate verification" set to "Off". What else could the issue be? I'm running a 2018 Mac Mini on MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.4. I have tried this in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, with the same result in each. Other team members are on Windows machines, and don't seem to be running into this issue. What am I missing here?